# Does Microsoft Project use OpenXML?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, openxml, openxml-sdk, ms-project

Does Microsoft Project 2010 use OpenXML?  Trying to load a .MPP project using the OpenXML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool, I get the error that the file is corrupt.  I'm not sure if this is from my particular project file or if it's just not supported.

I see that you can export to XML from Project, but I'd like to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OpenXML only describes the file format used by Microsoft Word, Excel and PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes apparently.